# JMeter non-persistent connections

Tags: jmeter

I have a need to generate non-persistent HTTP requests. Is there a way to configure JMeter to close the TCP connection after every request, and preferably, send the `Connection: close` header? Also, since each request will have their own TCP connection, what is the behavior of JMeter if no ports are available (as many will be in `TIME_WAIT` status, given a sufficiently high request frequency)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be going for [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) plugin where you can specify arbitrary request payload including any custom headers and additionally decide whether you would like to keep connection open or not.

[image: JMeter HTTP Raw Request]

By default you have `0` as "Timeout", it means that JMeter will wait for a free socket forever. You might amend this setting according to your test scenario in order to fail the sampler if connection will not be established in a timely fashion.

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter HTTP Raw Request installation]

Comment: Dmitri T, thank you for this detailed answer. I am still unclear, though, as to how to ask JMeter to close the TCP connection after receiving the response. I understand the `Timeout` specifies how long the client waits for a free socket before sending the request, and it seems the `Keep-alive` setting just adds a `Keep-alive header`, which is optional to begin with in HTTP 1.1.

Comment: To add: If my understanding is correct, adding the "Connection: close" header will not actually cause JMeter to do anything different (other than sending the header of course) - it's up to the server to interpret the header and close the connection. So I am wondering if JMeter has a setting to close the connection itself.

Comment: I will try to repeat loud and clear and try to translate "additionally decide whether you would like to keep connection open or not": if you don't tick "Keep connection open" box JMeter will close the connection after executing the request

Comment: Dmitri T, sorry, I missed that part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to check if enabling "Keep-alive connection" option in above "HTTP Raw Request" plugin is same as "Use KeepAlive" option in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler. Since this plugin doesn't support https(TLS) requests as per [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jmeter-plugins/4DnUtNPjf74/kva3lQFWpjMJ) comment.